# let $x^2-px+q=0$ and $x^2-qx+p=0$ both have unequal integral roots where $p\in{N}, q\in{N}$. Then the possible number of solutions (p,q) are?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried equating the discriminants to a perfect square to get integer roots but got stuck. Also tried using the sum and product of roots but did not find any way to incorporate p and q belonging to natural numbers condition

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use $p^2 - 4q \gt 0$ and $q^2 - 4p \gt 0$

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that but only got that p>4, q>4. Can you help with how to proceed further

Comment: @AnavAgrawal I wrote this answer on Toppr. You can check it out. Here's the link :  https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/x-let-x-2-p-x-q/